# The use of the phrase "be almost there" in context

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say a teacher have a student build a sentence with the present perfect correctly and the student can't get it right but he is very close. Is it natural to say *you are almost there* meaning you almost got it. For example:

> Try one more time! You are almost there.

If it doen't quite convey the message, then what would native English speakers say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is natural, and quite often used.

Another option you can also use is

> Try one more time! **You almost got it.**